# React admin nested resources issues

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-admin

I have set up my react admin to connect to my nestJS backend. For simple APIs, everything is working fine and I am able to perform CRUD properly. The issue arises for a situation like given below:

I have tables defined like this -

```
Pages table
Section table(foreign key -> pageId) - corresponds to the id in pages table
Widget table(foreign key -> sectionId) - corresponds to id in section table
```

I want to load pages as a datagrid and on click of a particular row, I should be able to get its required sections as a datagrid. Once I have the sections, I should be able to get the widgets on click of any section row. Also, I should be able to perform CRUD operations as well on each datagrid.

The sample POST requests are as follows:

```
for pages - >http://localhost:3010/config/pages
sections -  http://localhost:3010/config/pages/:pageId/sections
widgets -  http://localhost:3010/config/pages/:pageId/sections/:sectionId/widgets
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a [Show](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Show.html)-Component for your `Page`-Record with a [ReferenceManyField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield) inside. `Datagrid` can be a child of `ReferenceManyField`. So this could look somehow like that:

```
<ReferenceManyField
    {...props}             
    reference="sections"
    target="pageId">
       <Datagrid label="Sections">
           <TextField source="id"/>
           [...]
       </Datagrid>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

Alternatively when clicking on a page-row you could link to the main sections-list with a filter applied, so that only sections for the specific pageId are displayed, e.g. by linking to `/#/sections?displayedFilters={"pageId":true}&filter={"pageId":123}`. This would require you to setup the corresponding filter ui in the `List`-Component.